# Debugging Chrome using Devtools and look for a specific word being assign into a variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

Is there any option to debug and look for a specific word being assigned into a variable using Chrome Devtools?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: will CTRL + f  work? it opens finder in most applications

Comment: I'm actually looking for a word assigned into a variable for example any_var = <word>. I want to know where a specific word is being assigned into.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you know at least which file it'll be located in, and the specific word you mention isn't something generic that would be expected commonly within the file, then ctrl+f as suggested by cubesareneat will work best.

If even that returns many results, you could add an equals sign before the word to narrow the results down further.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is actually want to know where some specific word is being assigned into any variable on the backend and pause the debugging process if some specific word found assigned.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your wording of it, but if by backend you mean some sort of server then there won't really be any way to see that assignment. Presuming that this wasn't what you were saying, there isn't really going to be any way to stop all processes once a variable is assigned, without direct input in your actual code to exit once assigned. Why is this debugging process necessary or easier to be done through Chrome Devtools versus modifications/logging in your code?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to debug someone elses code, and I do not know where that specific word comes out. That's why I'm trying to know is there any possible way to look for a specific word/data pass or being assigned into a variable. It could be any variable as long it has a target value stored in it.